# Adding existing user custom field value to a woocommerce product

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I am assigning each product in WooCommerce to an author. Each author, when they sign up, adds in a short bio and this is saved with the author's user account. People are signing up with Profile Press.

I would like to insert this bio field into each product this author creates but I can seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not specify where the user field is saved to (meta key), or where you want it inserted in the product

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an action when a new product is inserted (and not when updated).  As you did not specify the meta key this field is stored under the user as, OR the meta key of where you want it stored on the product:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'smyles_insert_user_product_data', 10, 3 );

function smyles_insert_user_product_data( $post_ID, $post, $update ){

    if( $update || $post->post_type !== 'product' ){
        return;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if( $user_id ){
        $short_bio = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'some_meta_key', true );
        if( ! empty( $short_bio ) ){
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'product_meta_key', $short_bio );
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that the "short bio" is stored in the user's meta, so you need to figure out that meta key and replace `some_meta_key` in the code above with correct one for the user.

You then also need to define what meta key you want to use to set that value in the product with, and replace `product_meta_key` above.

To find the user meta key used, you can use my User Meta Display plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta-display/ (it's a bit out-dated but still works)

**UPDATE:**

To update the description (`post_content`) before data in inserted into the database use this instead:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'smyles_insert_user_product_data', 10, 2 );

function smyles_insert_user_product_data( $data, $postarr ){

    // Non-empty ID means it's an update (don't want to modify on update)
    if( ! empty( $postarr['ID'] ) || ! array_key_exists( 'post_type', $postarr ) || $postarr['post_type'] !== 'product' ){
        return $data;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if( $user_id ){
        $short_bio = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'some_meta_key', true );
        if( ! empty( $short_bio ) ){
            $short_bio = wp_kses( $short_bio, true );
            $data['post_content'] = wp_slash( $short_bio );
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. How can I find the corresponding meta-key for that bio field?

Comment: @ZCrow it's a little bit out-dated but still works, you can use my User Meta Display plugin to figure out what the user meta key is https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta-display/

Comment: Thanks for the plugin suggestion. That gave me what I was looking for.

Comment: Still can't get this to go. I appreciate your patience. So, the user meta key is called "description". The product meta key I can use is "description" as well (I'm using the short description for the product's description). Here is my code:

Comment: function smyles_insert_user_product_data( $post_ID, $post, $update ){

    if( $update || $post->post_type !== 'product' ){
        return;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if( $user_id ){
        $short_bio = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', true );
        if( ! empty( $short_bio ) ){
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'description', $short_bio );
        }
    }
}

Comment: I'm trying to pull that into a product using: $description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_description', $post->post_description );

Comment: So it sounds like you're trying to update the actual `post_content` of the product, not any kind of post meta itself.  I added an update to the answer for modifying the post content before it's inserted into the database

Comment: Brilliant!! That worked. It posted the artist's bio into the woocommerce product description. And I can pull that out. Would be great if this could also work via update. For example, if the author updated their bio in their user account, the bio that is in product would also update. Right now it appears that it would require a manual update to each product.

Comment: @ZCrow that's an entirely different question/issue as that would require an action when the user's meta is updated to then update all associated products as well -- which means it would have to somehow be stored in the user's meta all the products then loop over each one updating it.  Open a new question regarding that and post link here and ill try and help if i have time.

Comment: @ZCrow Please don’t forget to accept the answer if this resolves your issue (answer will be marked with green check) — this helps other to know that your question/issue has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks. I will create a new question. I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Would anyone be able to provide some guidance in getting the product author's email to populate the the custom product meta fields? I tried to tweak this but unfortunately I have no idea what I'm doing. Thanks in advance for any help.