# Updating WooCommerce product field when product author updates profile field

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-meta

This is a continuation/variation on this issue: [Adding existing user custom field value to a woocommerce product](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329260/adding-existing-user-custom-field-value-to-a-woocommerce-product?answertab=votes#tab-top)

While this solution worked, ideally, it would be great if when the product author updates their bio (description meta tag), all the products they created would also be updated with this update (in this case the $post->post_content meta field).

Answer (score 0):

So combined with that code for setting the value before it's inserted in the db, you also need to add this code to add the post ID to an array stored in the user's meta (after it has been updated):

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'smyles_update_user_products', 10, 3 );

function smyles_update_user_products( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {

    if ( $post->post_type !== 'product' ) {
        return;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( ! empty( $user_id ) ) {

        $user_products = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_products', true );

        if ( is_array( $user_products ) && ! in_array( $post_ID, $user_products ) ) {
            $user_products[] = $post_ID;
        } else {
            $user_products = array( $post_ID );
        }

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_products', $user_products );
    }
}
```

Then add a hook when the user's meta is updated, to then trigger the update on all of those associated posts:

```
add_action( 'updated_user_meta', 'smyles_update_post_on_user_desc_update', 10, 4 );

function smyles_update_post_on_user_desc_update( $meta_id, $user_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value ){

    if( $meta_key !== 'some_meta_key' ){
        return;
    }

    // Probably not necessary, but just in case
    if( ! empty( $user_id ) ){
        $user_products = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_products', true );

        if( ! empty( $user_products ) && is_array( $user_products ) ){

            // Remove our action to prevent loop
            remove_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'smyles_insert_user_product_data', 10 );

            foreach( (array) $user_products as $product_id ){

                $my_post = array(
                    'ID'           => $product_id,
                    'post_content' => $_meta_value,
                );

                wp_update_post( $my_post );

            }

            // Add it back after were done
            add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'smyles_insert_user_product_data', 10, 2 );
        }
    }
}
```

You **may** be able to just remove setting the actual `post_content` value and just call `wp_update_post` (and remove the `remove_action` and `add_action` calls), allowing that action to still handle this (but i haven not tested the code so i'm not sure if WordPress will still do an update if all you pass is just the `ID`)

Comment: Thank you! I will see if I can get this to work. I appreciate your efforts very much.

Comment: @ZCrow no problem ,let me know if there are any issues

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had a chance to implement yet but hopefully soon.